# Limitations of XUL

Tags: xul

I'm trying to understand if it is worth the pain to learn XUL more thoroughly.

If you have experience with a moderately complex project (like an independent application rather than a Firefox extension), can you tell me what your experience has been like?

I am particularly worried for feature which are not supported by the XUL framework natively. There are two possibilities: either create more XPCOM components, or using external tools. The latter approach is not completely satisfactory, as interprocess communication seems somehow lacking in XUL.

On the other hand, I have no knowledge of C++. How difficult would it be for a first time learner to wrap an existing library in XPCOM dressing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not written any XPCOM in my three years of developing XUL applications.  It does seem intimidating.  So far, though, I haven't had a good reason to create any XPCOM.  I do use some external tools - for reporting, working with mobile devices, etc.  I eventually figured out that you can at least get the STDOUT return value from a process that runs (at least on Windows, it seems that this particular feature might not be consistent across platforms).  That allowed me to have at least a single return value, which allowed me to implement error handling.

I think that you will find that you can do quite a bit without touching XPCOM.  However, everything is not polished and easy, and there is not a large, helpful, developer community/ not much developer support, so it can be a frustrating learning experience.

If this is a large application, or an application that you might be adding other developers too, you may wish to consider choosing a more supported development platform.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to do (yet another?) an application to manage photos by metadata. But the obvious problem is that no XPCOM component is able to read or write IPTC or XMP data, so I have to rely on external programs. As you have read in my other thread, this already created problems, because I have to spawn a new process for each photo. So I'm wondering whether learning how to wrap an existing library in a XPCOM component would be a better idea.

Comment: I don't know much about IPTC or XMP data, but it may be that if you can't just parse that data from an nsiFile object, and if you are going to use XUL, then you will need to look @ using XPCOM.  I know lots of people do it and there is documentation, I just can't speak to how easy or hard it is.